# MySQL prepare vs PHP mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if there was any difference between the MySQL PREPARE/EXECUTE clauses and the PHP mysqli prepare/execute methods? Are either better or worse at preventing injections?

I am curious because I am writing a few database stored procedures and in one, the table and attributes are not known on compilation. I could write the data in as static, but the query is a bit complex and it would just bloat the procedure with a lot of control logic. It got me thinking about this though and I just wondered whether it is better if, when I just needed a simple statement, I write a short procedure with dynamic SQL or just prepare and bind with PHP.

Also I apologize if this is a repeat and would of course welcome a link to an already answered SO question. However, I looked generally on google and could not really find much in the way of a specific answer to this.

Comment: Have you tried [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)? It clearly states that `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` statements are an interface into the same preparation mechanism, but less efficient than application-side prepared statements.

Comment: [Overview - PHP manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: The PHP manual doesn't really answer the question of injection I had and neither does the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP mysqli is a layer, in PHP, around MySQL's prepare / execute functionality.

Both will keep you safe from SQL injection as long as everything that comes in from users is stuffed into a bound variable.

Prepared statements, handled either way, make for more efficient high-volume operation too.  In MySQL the efficiency gain is modest compared to the high-priced DBMSs like Oracle, but it is still worth every bit of the trouble.

If you need to have table names as "variables" in your app, that's OK,  You can't treat table names as bound variables though.  So you need to be totally paranoid about any user input that results in the construction of these table names.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. So since the mysqli layer is just a wrapper for the regular MySQL, they basically act the same way. Thanks! I'm not using the table names directly as they aren't very logical for the user to input. Rather, I'm using a something a little more clear for the user like "Table Name" then I parse that into what the table is actually named like "tableName" (because I love my CamalCase).

Comment: Right.  Just make sure your friendly local user can't give you a table name like ";DROP TABLES" !!

Comment: Well I think from further reading that'd be invalid right? I remember a document or faq saying that execute (in either case) only works for one statement. With "; drop tables --", that'd turn the query into two statements, and thus should not execute as I understand it.

Comment: Hopefully it's invalid.  But you should still make sure that table names, and other non-bind-variable parameters derived from user furnished input are extremely rigidly sanitized. Seriously, don't take any shortcuts here. Do it right! Please!

Answer (score 0):

As I answer it for 2020 and what I learned you should use to prepare and bind or bind inside execute with PDO, not with mysqli. It will be protected from injections and be safer.

Comment: And what's wrong with mysqli prepare? Spoiler: nothing wrong, it is as safe as PDO

Comment: They're equally safe. There are other reasons why you should consider PDO over MySQLi